# htaccess redirect all subdomains (except www) to index with parameters

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

What I'm trying to do is this:

```
sub.domain.com
```

to

```
domain.com/index.php?q=sub
```

and

```
 sub.domain.com/somefile.php
```

to

```
 domain.com/sub/index.php?q=sub&file=somefile.php
```

and

```
 sub.domain.com/somefile.php?m=12&r=12
```

to

```
 domain.com/sub/index.php?q=sub&file=somefile&m=12&r=12
```

and keep the address bar with the subdomain.

I got some code but it's not remotely doing what I need, so any help would be really appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On


#Rewrite foo.domain.com/foo/bar to /index.php?q=foo&page=foobar
#in the condition pattern bellow, we match against any http_host string that doesnt start with www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^((?!www).+)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
#if the above condition is met, the rewrite the request
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?q=%1&file=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```